# jQuery Add / Remove class to non-sibling DIV ID?

Tags: javascript, css

I am relatively new to Javascript, and I am having issues with the following script:

```
// Keep Focus On Site Menu //
function menuFocus() {
    $('#menu').addClass('hover');
}

function menuBlur() {
    $('#menu').removeClass('hover');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submenu-mgmt').hover(menuFocus,menuBlur);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submenu-label').hover(menuFocus,menuBlur);
});
```

Essentially, I am trying to keep a 'hover' effect on a non-sibling DIV ID while a user is hovered over a secondary menu system using two separate DIV IDs.  I designed it to include 3 DIV IDs, '#Menu' is the header menu area. '#Submenu-Mgmt' and '#Submenu-Label' are both hidden on arrival but can be opened by clicking a link that shows / hides the DIVs.

This is a for a page that is currently live -- and while this issue won't make or break the site, it would be a nice touch as the menu area loses focus while a user's mouse is hovered over the submenus.

Page in question: http://www.parkthevan.com/index.php.

Comment: Also, you don't need any javascript at all. If you nest the submenus _inside_ the main menu elements, then the main menu items will stay "hovered". It would also be more semantic. See: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: This is definitely what I needed.  After struggling with the sample posted by @anndr0id (simply didn't work with my setup) -- I simply ended up placing my submenu HTML within the same DIV as Menu -- problem solved, no code tweaking or javaSCRIPT necessary.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Nice work, glad it worked for you! You might want to write up a quick explanation and answer your own question to help out future searchers :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the additional submenu IDs to the add class function should do it. If your hover class has additional display qualities other than to hide/show the class, you could use the .css as well. I'll include them both here for you. :) (note the // is a comment in javascript) You'll Also want to do the same for the remove - and you only need your document ready once.

```
    function menuFocus() {
       $('#menu, #submenu-mgmt, #submenu-label').addClass('hover');
       // or
       //$('#submenu-mgmt, #submenu-label').css('display', 'block');
    }

    function menuBlur() {
       $('#menu, #submenu-mgmt, #submenu-label').removeClass('hover');
       // or
       //$('#submenu-mgmt, #submenu-label').css('display', 'none');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#submenu-mgmt').hover(menuFocus,menuBlur);
       $('#submenu-label').hover(menuFocus,menuBlur);
    });
```